# Split numeric (%Y.%m) column into two columns

Tags: r

So i have a time series with the following format:

| Date(numeric, %Y.%m) | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1951.01 | 12 |
| 1951.02 | 13 |

I'm trying to separate the date column into two columns like that:

| year | month | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1951 | 01 | 12 |
| 1951 | 02 | 13 |

I've tried using the separate() function from tidyr and it kinda worked. However, for some reason it is dropping the 0 at month 10, like so:

```
data$month 
... 8 9 1 11 ...
```

I suspect it has something to do with coercing it to character(?). I've tried using substr() and it didnt work either, same problem. Is there a better way of doing this?

My code:

```
data %>%
separate(Date, into = c("year","month"))
```

** Edit

I think It is definitely because I'm coercing the numeric date to a character.

```
as.character(1951.10)
[1] "1951.1"
```

Reproducible sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c(1951.01, 1951.02, 1951.1), 
                     value = c(12,13, 14)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl","data.frame"))
```

Comment: Try  to use `tstrsplit` function.

Comment: It is essential that you share a reproducible piece of your data in particular in this case where we would like to know the type of for example `Date` column.

Comment: You should use `dput` function to provide the data instead of just a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have numeric values in column `Date`, you should first to convert it into `character` and preserve two decimals. Here you can use `sprintf` to make it. Then you split the strings by `.`.

---

Try the code below

```
df %>%
  mutate(Date = sprintf("%.2f", Date)) %>%
  separate(Date, c("Year", "Month"), "\\.")
```

which gives

```
  Year  Month value
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 1951  01       12
2 1951  02       13
3 1951  10       14
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Date = c(1951.01, 1951.02, 1951.1), value = c(12,
13, 14)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl",
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Very nice solution. Is there a lubridate equivalence to `sprintf` function?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Sorry that I am not an expert on `lubridate`, but I think this is a basic numeric-to-character conversion problem.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding No it's totally ok. `sprintf` is fabulous function with great application written by c. There is no need to look for alternatives but I was just curious and your solution is by far the best one.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated**
Since I realized your `Date` column values are numeric, I didn't want to abandon my code in a state that is not working for your purpose. So you can also use the following solution to format the values in `Date` column while not losing month values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)


df %>%
  mutate(Date = format(Date, format = "%Y.%m.%d"), 
         Date = ym(Date), 
         Year = year(Date), 
         Month = month(Date)) %>%
  select(-Date) %>%
  relocate(-value)


# A tibble: 3 x 3
   Year Month value
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  1951     1    12
2  1951     2    13
3  1951    10    14
```

Using data proposed by Mr. @ThomasIsCoding to verify the output.

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c(1951.01, 1951.02, 1951.1), 
                     value = c(12,13, 14)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl","data.frame"))
```

Comment: Nice approach Anoushiravan!!

Comment: Thank you dear @TarJae, That's very kind of you.

Comment: Thank you for you answer @Anoushiravan! I'm relatively new to this, so I'm still learning how to be clear and provide enough info about the problems.

Comment: @LucasMFF my pleasure. I hope my solution also works for your purpose. It's totally ok as we are all in a constant learning process and I would suggest you try as many solutions for a single problem as possible. However, `sprintf` function is extremely useful and if you read the documentation you will find out yourself. That was the best solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

First transform to `character` then `separate`. If you want integer just add `type.convert(as.is = TRUE)`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  separate(`Date(numeric, %Y.%m)`, as.character(c("Year", "Month"))) %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
  Year  Month value
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 1951  01       12
2 1951  02       13
###
# integer
   Year Month value
  <int> <int> <int>
1  1951     1    12
2  1951     2    13
```

Comment: I think `separate` gives an error in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(date = c("1951.01","1951.02","1951.10"))
dt[,c("year","month") := tstrsplit(date,".",fixed = TRUE)]

#      date year month
#1: 1951.01 1951    01
#2: 1951.02 1951    02
#3: 1951.10 1951    10
```

Comment: Same problem, it works but at month 10 it drops the 0.

Comment: That's not the truth. See my updated data of month 10.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough in my post, sorry. Your date column is of character type, so it works fine. Mine is numeric, that is why I'm having this problem. The fuction is coercing it to character and messing it up.